# R - partykit - custom model tree nodes and splits

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, party

In package partykit there is a way to build custom trees by specifying predictor and split. For example:

```
data("WeatherPlay", package = "partykit")

#create a split
sp_o <- partysplit(3L, breaks = 75) 

#create a node
n1 <- partynode(id = 1L, split = sp_o, kids = lapply(2L:3L, partynode))

#and make a "tree" out of it
t2 <- party(
  n1,
  data = WeatherPlay,
  fitted = data.frame(
    "(fitted)" = fitted_node(n1, data = WeatherPlay),
    "(response)" = WeatherPlay$play,
    check.names = FALSE
  ),
  terms = terms(play ~ ., data = WeatherPlay),
)

t2 <- as.constparty(t2)
t2
plot(t2)
```

Is this possible for model trees (returned by mob())? Can i build the tree node by node, and then fit specified function to terminal nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, it is possible to build a `"modelparty"` object (as returned by `mob()`) by hand. However, there is not a simple coercion function like `as.constparty()` in the example you cite. The reason is that for building the model trees, and for printing and especially predicting with them, much more detailed information about the model is needed.

I would recommend to build the tree structure (`"partynode"`) first, then fill the overall `$info` slot (with `call`, `formula`, `Formula`, `terms`, `fit`, `control`, `dots`, and `nreg`). And then it should be possible to call `refit.modelparty()` to refit the models in all the terminal nodes. And this can then be used to fill the `$node$info` (with `coefficients`, `objfun`, `nobs`, ...).

Disclaimer: All of this is completely untested. But instead of mimicking `"modelparty"` you could, of course, also create your own way of storing the models in the `"party"` object and just use more basic building blocks provided by `partykit`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was not sure if im not missing some already implemented tools for this... so that im not reinventingnthe wheel :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. We might extend `partykit` in the future in this direction. We are working on a couple of ideas that would allow plugging in different split criteria etc. But at the moment the best approach is to "roll your own" tree.